Accessing the same instance of view model between to compose screens while using voyager navigation
I have created two screens and I want to access the same data from the dame view model
class GalleryFolderScreen() : Screen {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        GallerFolderScreenView()
    }
    @OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun GallerFolderScreenView() {
        //val viewModelScreen = getViewModel<View_Model_GalleryPickerScreen>()
        val viewModelScreen: View_Model_GalleryPickerScreen = hiltViewModel()
        val folders by viewModelScreen.folders.collectAsState()
//reduced for simplicity
LaunchedEffect{   viewModelScreen.loadImages()
 
        LazyColumn {
            items(folders.size) { folder ->

                folders[folder].name?.let { Text(text = it) }

            }
        }
    }
} 


//Screen 2
class GalleryImagesScreen() : Screen {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        GalleryImagesScreenView()
    }
    @OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun GalleryImagesScreenView() {
        //val viewModelScreen = getViewModel<View_Model_GalleryPickerScreen>()
        val viewModelScreen: View_Model_GalleryPickerScreen = hiltViewModel()
        val images by viewModelScreen.images.collectAsState()
        LazyColumn {
            items(images.size) { image ->

                images[image].name?.let { Text(text = it) }

            }
        }
    }
} 

@HiltViewModel
class View_Model_GalleryPickerScreen @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
private val _images = MutableStateFlow<List<GalleryPickImage>>(emptyList())
val images: StateFlow<List<GalleryPickImage>> = _images.asStateFlow()


private val _folders = MutableStateFlow<List<GalleryPickFolder>>(emptyList())
val folders: StateFlow<List<GalleryPickFolder>> = _folders.asStateFlow()


fun loadImages() {}

I can get list of folders on the first screen but can not get list of images in the second screen
